# How to use a url which returns a csv in HTML? in other words how to display the data from that csv file in my webpage?

Tags: java, javascript, html, api

let me be real specific. I have this URL- http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XOM+BBDb.TO+JNJ+MSFT&f=snd1l1yr

this url returns a csv file.i want to use this url to print the data present in it in my webpage. now the problem is that i dont know how to get the data into the html code.does it need javascript?

i want to know if i should use the `<url>` tag in html.i dont think that will work.or is there any other way to do it (if it is possible)?

note: i want to use html,javascript,java(if required)

P.S: to be more precise this is a yahoo stock api.

any help is appreciated.

P.S: doing this using XML will also be very helpful. because there is another api url that returns XML data. (google stock api) e.g. http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=grasim

Comment: Javascript code to parse CSV data   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data

Comment: What have you done so far? Put some code that you may have already written

Answer (score 2):

You want to get some framework such as JQuery and form a request to this url.

On the success code of the request you want to Parse the output using some CSV Reader.

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/csv  May suit your needs and then all you do from that point is spit out the array to the page.

Sorry I cant be more precise but I hope this points you in the right direction.  I'm sure others will give much better answers.

I have created a sample here I got some XSS problems but If you ask around stack or check existing questions you should find the final solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/gWBBE/

And also although this is for University people at stack do this to help each-other not to do other peoples homework.

Comment: but i m not at all familiar wid jquery. moreover i HAVE to use javascript only. thats my institute's instruction. :)

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1):

```
<object data="quotes.txt"></object>
```

you can use object tag to embedded any file or webpage to display into any webpage.

And also have look by using framework

http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxDataView/samples/03_loading/01_xml.html

Comment: u mean i should put the url in place of "quotes.txt"?

Comment: yes, but if that url should have a valid file format to read browser. some plugins also available for view csv file

Answer (score 1):

You could also start using Yahoo's own [Javascript library](http://yuilibrary.com/).

It will provide you with YUI IO (ajax) posibilities to fetch data. [Here](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/) you can find a few simple examples on how to use YUI IO on your page to get other sites' data.

Now, when you do that, you can also use [YUI datatable](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/) to show that data in the web page without having to produce your own html, YQL (yahoo query language), datasources, and a lot of other useful things.

Now, your question seems a bit specific, but it covers a lot, so the answers are such too.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all boils down to requesting the data and then parsing and displaying it.

Just send a httprequest to that url and work with the response.
Missed the callback on the initial answer, readystate 4 signals data transfer completion.

Then in plain js it looks sth like this:

```
function httpGet(url)
{
 var xmlHttp = null;

 xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
 xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction;
 xmlHttp.send( null );
}

function callbackFunction()
{
 if (xmlHttp.readyState != 4)
 return;

 var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

At least then u can parse the response and work with it as you like.
This link might be helpful: [Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Comment: You can't do return `xmlHttp.responseText`. Well, you can but it will be empty. You should do whatever you need in `onreadystatechange` callback of xmlHttp. Another option - synchronous request, but it will freeze web page until request is done.